# Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova. Could not get serial number of device from the Android Debug Bridge

Tags: cordova, deployment, adb

The emulator is launched successfuly, but the apk deployment does not work. Visual Studio 2015 show me the following error:

> Could not get serial number of device from the Android Debug Bridge
>   (adb.exe). Please stop the ADB server process and try again.

If I try to drag and drop apk manually into emulator, the emulator show me the following error:

> File transfer failed. Error: Unable to install the file through Adb.
>   Connecting to Android Device using Adb failed. empty host name

All paths in `Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Environment Variables` and `adb.exe` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Environment Variables in which you need to set path C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

if you have override ADT_HOME and map with local Android SDK,Please review following guide line

If the emulator is running, but it does not appear to be connected to ADB (Android Debug Bridge) or it does not appear in Android tools that make use of ADB (for example, Android Studio or Eclipse), you may need to adjust where the emulator looks for ADB. The emulator uses a registry key to identify the base location of your Android SDK, and looks for the \platform-tools\adb.exe file under that directory. To modify the Android SDK path used by the emulator:

- Open Registry Editor by selecting Run from the Start buttons context menu, typing regedit in the dialog box, and choosing OK.
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools in the folder tree on the left.
- Modify the Path registry variable to match the path to your Android SDK.

[For more detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt228282.aspx#Visual%20Studio%20gets%20stuck%20trying%20to%20deploy%20the%20app%20to%20the%20emulator%20or%20the%20emulator%20does%20not%20appear%20as%20a%20debug%20target%20in%20other%20IDEs)